# Badge icons in Achievements section erroneously correspond to the current site

Tags: bug, badges, top-bar, achievements-dialog

This screenshot says it all:

I am on ELL.SE, opening a recent notification in top frame.

The notification is about a Badge received on Linguistics.SE site.

The icon apparently belongs to the **theme of ELL.SE**,
while it must be from the **theme of Linguistics.SE**.

[image: Wrong icon]